# Seeding data rails with a website that uses paperclip to upload images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
artistOne.arts.create!(
    genre:'Interior',
    description:'Interior paintings/drawings typically exclude or de-emphasize the presence of people or pets.',
    price:200,
    length:30,
    width:40,
    medium:'Oil',
    artist: artistOne,
    user: user, 
    :image_file_name => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/artistOne.jpg'))
)
```

I need help on the method of seeding data images since my website uses `paperclip` to upload images. I wanted to know if I'm on the write track in terms of seeding an image file?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Just add to your model the attachment on the `image_file_name` field:

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file : image_file_name
end

artistOne.arts.create!(
    genre:'Interior',
    description:'Interior paintings/drawings typically exclude or de-emphasize the presence of people or pets.',
    price:200,
    length:30,
    width:40,
    medium:'Oil',
    artist: artistOne,
    user: user, 
    image_file_name: File.open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb')
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put your file in your public folder, read it and transform it into base64 content :

```
image_file_name: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Base64.encode64(File.open('public/path_to_file.jpg', 'rb').read)
```

Don't forget to

```
require 'base64'
```

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to his question.